# STL Vectorised Map - Looking for Best Practice

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl

I'm not too experienced with STL, so I'm unsure of the best approach here.

I have a set of actions, each tied to a unique ID. To ensure I don't duplicate the actions, I initially thought to store them in a `std::map`, keyed on the ID. However, I need to retain strict ordering internally *a la* `std::vector`, such that when I unwind my actions they appear in the reverse order they were added.

Any given list of actions could be anywhere from one or two items, to several thousand. Will I lose anything if I switch to manually checking a `vector` for duplicates (i.e., iterating through and checikng IDs)? Or is there some form of `map` or other container I can use that lets me lookup by ID, but doesn't internally sort or re-order my elements?

Comment: One crude option is simply to use both ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [boost:multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) map, which can support order of insertion for the map.

```
struct Item 
{
      string name;
      int data;
};
struct ItemTag {};
typedef multi_index_container<
    Item,
    indexed_by<
        random_access<>, // this index represents insertion order
        hashed_unique< tag<ItemTag>, member<Item, string, &Item::name> >
    >
> ItemsMap;
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a solution. However (and it may be heresy!), I'm not currently using Boost, and it looks like a fairly heavyweight library to bring in just to solve this problem (this is a mostly MFC app where I'm trying to bring in STL with newer additions, but I'm not retrofitting the existing `CArray` and `CMap` stuff).

Comment: Then I would propose to use both collections (map + vector) at the same time. Map will give you fast lookup, and vector will keep the order.

Comment: Forgive me for being dense, but do you mean use a `map` purely for lookup/duplicate checking, and a `vector` for storage (or perhaps a [deque](http://www.linuxsoftware.co.nz/containerchoice.png) is what I need following this)? So my trade-off is slightly increased storage (perhaps) through my `map` of `int` IDs?

Comment: Yes, as you said. But the 'storage' depends on exact type you put in the collection (value, pointer, smart pointer). If you store your items by value, then you could have vector<Item> and map<int, Item *>. So every time you add new element you add it to both collections, you put value to the vector and pointer to it into the map.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me that you need [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

> The Boost Multi-index Containers Library provides a class template named multi_index_container which enables the construction of containers maintaining one or more indices with different sorting and access semantics. Indices provide interfaces similar to those of STL containers, making using them familiar. The concept of multi-indexing over the same collection of elements is borrowed from relational database terminology and allows for the specification of complex data structures in the spirit of multiply indexed relational tables where simple sets and maps are not enough. A wide selection of indices is provided, modeled after analogous STL containers like std::set, std::list and hashed sets.